# How to create different URLs for items in a drop down list on a product page?

Tags: magento, url, drop-down-menu

I am not a coder, and I am working for a company involved in e-commerce activities, so please help me!

Currently we are looking to merge two different aspects of the business, where we will have the other company arms website detailing the product variations (i.e. Product A in sizes 1, 2, 3 and 4) on their page as separate enteries as part of their mission driven section, which link directly to our product page.

The issue we have is, on our website we have a drop down menu, and what we want to achieve is for the when the visitor selects the buy on the product page for Product A in Size 2 it links directly to our ecommerce page with a pre filled in drop down menu for that exact product selection.

Does anyone know how we could achieve this in Magento? Could this be done in custom URLs?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: so you're asking for a link on site A to a product, which will automatically select the correct size of the product on site B based off which link they click on site A

Comment: Yes, that is correct :). So we sell sports equipment, and Site A will have 2 seperate listings, but site B will only have 1 listing with drop down menus to selecting sizings etc.

What we want to avoid is customer clicking the link for size A on Site A and then arriving on our product site and them having to reconfigure the item.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about configuring magento.

Answer (score 1):

To preselect a simple product in a configurable product, the address of a simple product should look like this for example:

> **`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html#143=167&93=53`**

where `/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html` - configurable product URL,

`143`, `93` - attributes IDs,

`167`, `53` - option IDs.

In order to change the URL of simple products, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for **`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getProductUrl()`**, where to generate the URL as in the example above.

---

I made `VCT Simple Product URL` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem.